# checking databse for permission and redirecting if not found

Tags: php, mysql, session, redirect, permissions

I have a table containing usertypes and pages eg

**page  usertype**
index.php   1 
index.php   2 
test.php    1

so that only specific user types can see a page. I want to put it in my header.php file so that the browser checks whether that user has permission to view the page and takes them back to the login screen if they do not.

When a user logs in the usertype is stored in the session variables.

I am putting the following in the header.php so that it can go on every page via an include but it always lets them view the page whatever their permissions. The not logged in and timeout parts are working but not the permissions part.

```
        <?php
session_start();
include'connect_db.php';
# Redirect if not logged in.
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'userid' ] ) ) { require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ; load() ; }

if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] ) { 
    //redirect to login.php
    header('Location:login.php'); 
} else{ //if we haven't expired:
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();

}

# check for permissions
$q = "SELECT usertypeid, page FROM permissions WHERE usertypeid='$_SESSION[ 'usertypeid' ]' AND page=basename( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] )" ;
    $r = mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q ) ; 
if( @mysqli_num_rows( $r ) == 1 ) {//permission in table 
    $_SESSION['last_page'] = $_SESSION['current_page']; 
} else{ //permission not in table 
    header('Location:login.php');
}
```

Comment: Run the query in sql using phpmyadmin or mysql workbench and show the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mysql query having syntax error.

```
$q = "SELECT usertypeid, page FROM permissions WHERE usertypeid='$_SESSION[ 'usertypeid' ]' AND page=basename( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] )" ;
```

Should be

```
$q = "SELECT usertypeid, page FROM permissions WHERE usertypeid='".$_SESSION[ 'usertypeid' ]."' AND page='".basename( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] )."';";
```